# CSS not rendering within React?

Tags: reactjs

I have tried for about a full day now to render css using React and I can not figuer it out after using the documentation on the React website.`

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from "./public/index.css";

function App() {
   return (
    <div className={styles.div}>
     <header className="App-header">
     <h1>Testing...</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
   );
  }

  export default App;`
```

`index.js`

```
 `    import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
       import App from './App';


  ReactDOM.render(

   <App / > ,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );`
```

`index.css`

`.div  { background-color: black; }`

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: If your are referring to the line of code `npx create-app_name-app` . yes, I used that to initiate the start of the app

Comment: @TheDevStar please do not drastically change a question

Comment: Especially for a question that is off topic for this site. For hardware support you may be able to find help on [su], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could define your style directly in your component like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
    div: {
        backgroundColor: 'black';
    }
};

function App() {
   return (
    <div style={styles.div}>
     <header className="App-header">
     <h1>Testing...</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
   );
  }

  export default App;
```

Note: in this case you have to write style in camelCase (`backgroundColor` and not `background-color`).

Comment: I am looking to keep the css in a separate file, but thank you for your input.

Comment: Ciao, and what about an intermediate solution? You colud put `const style = ...` in another file to keep style and component in different files. Could work.

Answer (score 0):

Your styles should not be in the `public` folder.

Add `index.css` to the folder that has your `index.js` file

Add `import './index.css';` to the top of `index.js` file. This will import the styles which will apply to the `App` component as well.

You do not need to import styles in the `App` component.

Remove `className={styles.div}` from the `div` tag in `App.js`.
The style for the div tag will come from the `index.css` that you have already imported.

All the styles you add in `index.css` will apply to your `App.js` component.

Comment: i will try this, however this is not what the React documentation recommends.

Comment: I thought it was common/best practice to store those files in a "public" folder, this is what most people have recommended to me.

Comment: When you create an application with `npx create-react-app <appname>`, the index.css file is present in the `src` folder not in the `public` folder. This css file is imported into the `index.js` file included in the same folder using  `import './index.css'  and applies to all containers added in the `index.js` file.

I can help better if you can post a github link to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Accordin to [React documentation about structure](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html) :

Its good that you put your `index.css` inside of the folder where your `index.js` stay, so your import be like: `import './index.css`. Yes, no name reference for css imports

Then reference in your elements by: `<div className="card">...rest of Your Element</div>` so your `.div` reference in `index.css` will be functional

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Your path says "./public/index.css" which would be a file named index.css inside a public folder under this index.js file. I'm guessing you probably actually mean "../public/index.css"

Secondly; using the className={styles.div} syntax is attempting to use CSS Modules. With create-react-app if you want to use css modules you need to name your css file "index.modules.css" and then it will work.

Doing the above two things will fix the issue. However; I would do as the others have stated and just skip the "import stylex from..." syntax and use the syntax that create-react-app uses in it's App.js page: aka import "./App.css"; then use styles like:

Comment: I have ran npx create-react-app has I though it was mandatory for the app to initialize, I have also looked over the React documentation a few times and it does not say anything about CSS rendering. I have deleted the entire project and decide to move forward with a different language.

Comment: Yes; if you do npx create-react-app myapp then it will create a folder myapp and you should have a react app created in there that is fully functional. There should already be an App.css that is linked to an App.js. I would suggest following the pattern that is already there and working inside of create-react-app

Comment: My goal here was to not use pre-made boilerplate coding.